# Stumped on code

Tags: php

Trying to fix the code. I'm pulling errors on lines 3, 5, and 9. I'm stumped. It seems pretty good, but its not :/

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']) {
    if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST[$_POST['comments'])) {
        $error = true;
    }else{

        $to = "theloregame@gmail.com"

        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);

        $subject = "Contact Form";

        $messages = "name: $name \r\n Email: $email \r\n Comments: $comments";
        $headers = "From:" . $name;
        $mailesent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers);

        if($mailsclient) {
            $sent = true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: On line 3 what's `$_POST[$_POST['comments']`? Compare with the other 2 `$_POST`s

Comment: What are the errors you are getting

Comment: Apparently dreamweaver anticipating my typing before hand. It gets way from me sometimes. Only error is line 9. I'll test it, see if it gives me a hint.

Comment: Came up as "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE"

Comment: `$to = "theloregame@gmail.com"` needs a semicolon

Comment: For one thing, this `empty($_POST[$_POST['comments']))` needs to be changed to `empty($_POST['comments']))`

Comment: Plus you're better off using `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` rather than `if($_POST['submit']) {`

Comment: @JulianaWilde The thing to learn here is to work your way down from the first error on line 3, and you probably would've caught the rest yourself :) Instead of taking all 3 errors at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing semi colon

```
$to = "theloregame@gmail.com"
```

should be

```
$to = "theloregame@gmail.com";
                             ^
```

and

```
empty($_POST[$_POST['comments'])
```

should be

```
empty($_POST['comments'])
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Staring at code all day, I tend to miss some things. Thank you again. I'll try to be more diligent.

Answer (score 1):

Error in  **empty($_POST[$_POST['comments'])**

```
   if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['comments']))
```

and Missing semi-colon:

```
$to = "theloregame@gmail.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']) 
{
    if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['comments'])) 
    {
        $error = true;
    }
  else{

        $to = "theloregame@gmail.com";

        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);

        $subject = "Contact Form";

        $messages = "name:".$name."\r\n Email:".$email."\r\nComments:".$comments;
        $headers = "From:" . $name;
        $mailesent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers);

        if($mailsclient) 
    {
            $sent = true;
        }
      }
}
?>
```

**Mistakes and their solutions:**

//syntax error near last condition  $_POST[$_POST

```
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST[$_POST['comments']))
```

changed to:

```
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST[$_POST['comments']))
```

//semicolon missing

```
$to = "theloregame@gmail.com"
```

changed to:

```
$to = "theloregame@gmail.com";
```

//concatenation

```
$messages = "name:".$name."\r\n Email:".$email."\r\nComments:".$comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $to = "theloregame@gmail.com";
```

// you need ; there

And a good approach is to comment the chunk of code, leave only 2-3 lines, see if you have error. If yes, you can easily find them, if no, add 2-3 more lines and try again.

Comment: and a better approach probably would be to use an IDE and look at error messages?

Comment: I belong to the old school and recommend to work with text editor ftp / ssh client and see errors on the server :) The advantage is that ou already develop and test on the  production environment (almost production)